# Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. exceeds block gas limit

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico, openzeppelin

I am trying to deploy my crowdsale contract using "truffle migrate --network ropsten".

I encounter this problem "Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. exceeds block gas limit"

Truffle config file

```
    // truffle.js
    require('dotenv').config();
    const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
    module.exports = {
      networks: {
        development: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 7545,
          gas: 9999999999,
         network_id: "*"
        },
        ropsten: {
            provider: function() { 
              return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNENOMIC,         "https://ropsten.infura.io/" + process.env.INFURA_API_KEY) },
            network_id: 3,
            gas: 4867350,
        },
      }
    };
```

Crowdsale.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";


/**
 * @title Crowdsale
 * @dev Crowdsale is a base contract for managing a token crowdsale,
 * allowing investors to purchase tokens with ether. This contract     implements
 * such functionality in its most fundamental form and can be extended to provide additional
 * functionality and/or custom behavior.
 * The external interface represents the basic interface for purchasing tokens, and conform
 * the base architecture for crowdsales. They are *not* intended to be modified / overridden.
 * The internal interface conforms the extensible and modifiable surface of crowdsales. Override
 * the methods to add functionality. Consider using 'super' where appropriate to concatenate
 * behavior.
 */
contract Crowdsale {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  using SafeERC20 for ERC20;

  // The token being sold
  ERC20 public token;

  // Address where funds are collected
  address public wallet;

  // How many token units a buyer gets per wei.
  // The rate is the conversion between wei and the smallest and indivisible token unit.
  // So, if you are using a rate of 1 with a DetailedERC20 token with 3 decimals called TOK
  // 1 wei will give you 1 unit, or 0.001 TOK.
  uint256 public rate;

  // Amount of wei raised
  uint256 public weiRaised;

  /**
   * Event for token purchase logging
   * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
   * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
   * @param value weis paid for purchase
   * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
   */
  event TokenPurchase(
    address indexed purchaser,
        address indexed beneficiary,
    uint256 value,
    uint256 amount
  );

  /**
   * @param _rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
   * @param _wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
   * @param _token Address of the token being sold
   */
  constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, ERC20 _token) public {
    require(_rate > 0);
    require(_wallet != address(0));
    require(_token != address(0));

    rate = 8 * (10**8);
    wallet = 0xF76075Cf3B674fB9656E393e9e17091B01243666;
    token = token = ERC20(0x0f26c1c05f1bbBC7Eff0488F1a98619e8a9758cf);
  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Crowdsale external interface
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   */
  function () external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.sender);
  }

  /**
   * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   */
  function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {

    uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
    _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    // calculate token amount to be created
    uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

    // update state
    weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

    _processPurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);
    emit TokenPurchase(
      msg.sender,
      _beneficiary,
      weiAmount,
      tokens
    );

    _updatePurchasingState(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

    _forwardFunds();
    _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
  }

  // -----------------------------------------
  // Internal interface (extensible)
  // -----------------------------------------

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to     revert state when conditions are not met. Use `super` in contracts that     inherit from Crowdsale to extend their validations.
   * Example from CappedCrowdsale.sol's _preValidatePurchase method: 
   *   super._preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, _weiAmount);
   *   require(weiRaised.add(_weiAmount) <= cap);
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _preValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    require(_beneficiary != address(0));
    require(_weiAmount != 0);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _postValidatePurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
   */
  function _deliverTokens(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    token.safeTransfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Not necessarily emits/sends tokens.
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
   */
  function _processPurchase(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _tokenAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    _deliverTokens(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
   * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
   */
  function _updatePurchasingState(
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    internal
  {
    // optional override
  }

  /**
   * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
   * @param _weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
   * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
   */
  function _getTokenAmount(uint256 _weiAmount)
    internal view returns (uint256)
  {
    return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
   */
  function _forwardFunds() internal {
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: current block gas limit of Ropsten is `4700036`; your contract deployment seems need more gas than that then you encounter the error

Comment: so what's the solution? can't I deploy standard crowdsale contracts on ropsten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ropsten gas limit is currently hovering around 4,700,000.

It's unlikely that your contract actually needs that much to deploy, but since you specify `4867350` in your truffle.js, that is used as the max gas.

Try setting the gas in truffle.js to a lower number, such as `2000000` or so (you may need more depending on your contract).

Comment: thanks mate, always answering my questions instantly! :) It's a bit weird when I deployed my standard Token I had to put it as maximum, but crowdsale worked with 2,000,000... (I tried a number 4,600,000 before posting this question and the problem appeared again) -> do you have any idea why?

Comment: The block gas limit is not constant, so it usually varies by a few hundred thousand between blocks. It's odd that 4.6m won't work, though, it should not have had a 1 million difference in a short span of time.